# How to run a python program packaged with distutils from source in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I cloned a repo that has a python project such as [gitlabber](https://github.com/ezbz/gitlabber) that is supposed to be packaged with distutils. If I pick what looks to be the entry point, I just get a module resolution error.

```py
gitlabber/gitlabber/__main__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .cli import main

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I can run it by

pip install . and then running it as a command.

```
pip install .
gitlabber -t -i
```

But I want to change the source code, run in debug mode, and run without installing it with pip every time, like a normal python developer. How do I do that?

I seriously did google this and did not find any good material. Probably because it's assumed to be too basic.

Comment: Either `pip isntall -e .` (editable install) or `python3 -m gitlabber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install with a setup.py file:

```
python setup.py install
```

To install with pip in edit mode use -e.  I think this is what you are looking for.

```
pip install -e .
```